# Evaluate Post order expression

Tags: data-structures, infix-notation, postfix-notation

What will be the resulted value of `7 4 3 + - 3 9 2 / + * 2 ^ 5 *`

It is in post order. So how can I get the value of this expression?

Comment: Read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate from right side.
If it is operator than it is intermediate node. otherwise, it is leaf.

So,
"*" is root of all.
"5" is leaf on right side.
Than start "^" as other intermediate node.
"2" is right leaf.
"*" is left intermediate node.
and so on.

So final equation will be

`(((7(43+)-)(3(92/)+)*)2^)5*
=>
(((7-(4+3)) * (3+(9/2)))^2) * 5
= 0`